# How to create slider with at time 3 slide display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

for web designing to develop simple slider all slider work properly but i need slide in different way like at a time 3 slider display then by clicking forward and backward arrow to go next previous more information for that show below images slider i need this below slider code in html

[image]

Comment: which slider?? And SO is not for serving code. First try and if you get any issue then come here and ask.

Comment: please so above image slider i need this type slider in web designing using html, css,javascipt etc....

Comment: @RahulRaval try to implement the Slider by yourself. And if you face some coding side issue post here your issue!

Comment: yes  i try it still they not work my code is below file http://paio-co-kr.github.io/carousel-3d/    please check this code and help to me.

Answer (score 0):

> try this

[bxslider](http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-static-number-slides)

use property of maxSlides = 3 will display 3 slides per page.

[wowslider](http://wowslider.com/jquery-carousel-vernisage-stack-v-demo.html)

carousel option used.

Comment: thanks for replied but its not my perfectly solution,  i need above images for slider